# Align Table Center

Tags: r, center-align

I am doing a problem in Swirl. Week 2 R Programming Environment Chapter 12 Data Manipulation

Swirl wants me to make a table that looks exactly like this:

```
 Pclass   agecat    Sex      N     survivors   perc_survived
 <int>   <fctr>    <chr>   <int>     <int>         <dbl>
   1    Under 15  female     2         1        50.000000
   1    Under 15    male     3         3       100.000000
   1    15 to 50  female    70        68        97.142857
   1    15 to 50    male    72        32        44.444444
   1    Over 50   female    13        13       100.000000
   1    Over 50     male    26         5        19.230769
```

So far,

```
>library(dplyr)
> titanic_4 <- titanic %>% 
+     select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
+     filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
+     mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.99, 50, 150), 
+                         include.lowest = TRUE,
+                         labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50",
+                                    "Over 50"))) %>%
+     group_by(Pclass,agecat,Sex) %>%
+     summarize(N=n(), survivors = sum(Survived))%>%
+     mutate(perc_survived = survivors/N*100)
> 
> head (titanic_4)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   Pclass, agecat [3]
  Pclass   agecat    Sex     N survivors perc_survived
   <int>   <fctr>  <chr> <int>     <int>         <dbl>
1      1 Under 15 female     2         1     50.000000
2      1 Under 15   male     3         3    100.000000
3      1 15 to 50 female    70        68     97.142857
4      1 15 to 50   male    72        32     44.444444
5      1  Over 50 female    13        13    100.000000
6      1  Over 50   male    26         5     19.230769
>
```

Now, it looks like I need to figure out how to add another component into my pipe that will get the table to all columns of the table to align-center.

So far I have tried scale(center = TRUE, scale = TRUE) to the end of the pipe, which gave me the Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric because scale only works with a matrix.

```
> titanic_4 <- titanic %>% 
+     select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
+     filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
+     mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.99, 50, 150), 
+                         include.lowest = TRUE,
+                         labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50",
+                                    "Over 50"))) %>%
+     group_by(Pclass,agecat,Sex) %>%
+     summarize(N=n(), survivors = sum(Survived))%>%
+     mutate(perc_survived = survivors/N*100)%>%
+     scale(center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
> 
> head (titanic_4)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   Pclass, agecat [3]
  Pclass   agecat    Sex     N survivors perc_survived
   <int>   <fctr>  <chr> <int>     <int>         <dbl>
1      1 Under 15 female     2         1     50.000000
2      1 Under 15   male     3         3    100.000000
3      1 15 to 50 female    70        68     97.142857
4      1 15 to 50   male    72        32     44.444444
5      1  Over 50 female    13        13    100.000000
6      1  Over 50   male    26         5     19.230769
```

Next, I tried format(justify=center) to the end of the pipe, but the result was not what I am looking for.

```
> titanic_4 <- titanic %>% 
+     select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
+     filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
+     mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.99, 50, 150), 
+                         include.lowest = TRUE,
+                         labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50",
+                                    "Over 50"))) %>%
+     group_by(Pclass,agecat,Sex) %>%
+     summarize(N=n(), survivors = sum(Survived))%>%
+     mutate(perc_survived = survivors/N*100)%>%
+     format(justify=center)
> print (titanic_4)
 [1] "# A tibble: 18 x 6"                                      "# Groups:   Pclass, agecat [9]"                         
 [3] "   Pclass   agecat    Sex     N survivors perc_survived" "    <int>   <fctr>  <chr> <int>     <int>         <dbl>"
 [5] " 1      1 Under 15 female     2         1    50.0000000" " 2      1 Under 15   male     3         3   100.0000000"
 [7] " 3      1 15 to 50 female    70        68    97.1428571" " 4      1 15 to 50   male    72        32    44.4444444"
 [9] " 5      1  Over 50 female    13        13   100.0000000" " 6      1  Over 50   male    26         5    19.2307692"
[11] " 7      2 Under 15 female    10        10   100.0000000" " 8      2 Under 15   male     9         9   100.0000000"
[13] " 9      2 15 to 50 female    61        56    91.8032787" "10      2 15 to 50   male    78         5     6.4102564"
[15] "11      2  Over 50 female     3         2    66.6666667" "12      2  Over 50   male    12         1     8.3333333"
[17] "13      3 Under 15 female    27        13    48.1481481" "14      3 Under 15   male    27         9    33.3333333"
[19] "15      3 15 to 50 female    74        33    44.5945946" "16      3 15 to 50   male   217        29    13.3640553"
[21] "17      3  Over 50 female     1         1   100.0000000" "18      3  Over 50   male     9         0     0.0000000"
```

Also, not what Swirl is looking for.
Next, I tried format.data.frame(digits=6, justify= "centre", width=10)

```
> titanic_4 <- titanic %>% 
+     select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
+     filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
+     mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.99, 50, 150), 
+                         include.lowest = TRUE,
+                         labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50",
+                                    "Over 50"))) %>%
+     group_by(Pclass,agecat,Sex) %>%
+     summarize(N=n(), survivors = sum(Survived))%>%
+     mutate(perc_survived = survivors/N*100)%>%
+     format.data.frame(digits=6, justify= "centre", width=10)
> head (titanic_4)
      Pclass     agecat        Sex          N  survivors perc_survived
1          1  Under 15    female            2          1      50.00000
2          1  Under 15     male             3          3     100.00000
3          1  15 to 50    female           70         68      97.14286
4          1  15 to 50     male            72         32      44.44444
5          1  Over 50     female           13         13     100.00000
6          1  Over 50      male            26          5      19.23077
```

next I tried format(digits=6, justify= "centre", width=10)

```
> titanic_4 <- titanic %>% 
+     select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
+     filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
+     mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.99, 50, 150), 
+                         include.lowest = TRUE,
+                         labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50",
+                                    "Over 50"))) %>%
+     group_by(Pclass,agecat,Sex) %>%
+     summarize(N=n(), survivors = sum(Survived))%>%
+     mutate(perc_survived = survivors/N*100)%>%
+     format(digits=6, justify= "centre", width=10)
> head (titanic_4)
[1] "# A\n#   tibble:\n#   18 x\n#   6"             "# Groups:  \n#   Pclass,\n#   agecat\n#   [9]"
[3] "   Pclass"                                     "    <int>"                                    
[5] " 1      1"                                     " 2      1"
```

next was

```
> titanic_4 <- titanic %>% 
+     select(Survived, Pclass, Age, Sex) %>%
+     filter(!is.na(Age)) %>%
+     mutate(agecat = cut(Age, breaks = c(0, 14.99, 50, 150), 
+                         include.lowest = TRUE,
+                         labels = c("Under 15", "15 to 50",
+                                    "Over 50"))) %>%
+     group_by(Pclass,agecat,Sex) %>%
+     summarize(N=n(), survivors = sum(Survived))%>%
+     mutate(perc_survived = survivors/N*100)%>%
+     format(justify= "centre")
> head (titanic_4)
[1] "# A tibble: 18 x 6"                                      "# Groups:   Pclass, agecat [9]"                         
[3] "   Pclass   agecat    Sex     N survivors perc_survived" "    <int>   <fctr>  <chr> <int>     <int>         <dbl>"
[5] " 1      1 Under 15 female     2         1    50.0000000" " 2      1 Under 15   male     3         3   100.0000000"
```

Any Ideas about how I can get my columns to center-align like the one at the beginning of the question?

Thanks,

Drew

When I attempt to submit my answer to Swirl, swirl gives me a clue.

```
> submit()

| Sourcing your script...


| Keep trying!

| Check the example output in the comments of the script I opened for you. Make sure the columns in your output are in the same order as shown
| in the example output in the script comments. Try running your code in the console and printing out the result to determine whether it's
| successfully generating the desired final data frame before you submit it.
```

Suggestions from Comments Section:
   Mr 42 noticed that my table contains rownames while the swirl table does not have rownames. I tried to use his suggestions to remove the rownames, but they were not successful.

I tried to turn off the rownames in head:

```
> head(titanic_4,rownames=FALSE)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   Pclass, agecat [3]
  Pclass   agecat    Sex     N survivors perc_survived
   <int>   <fctr>  <chr> <int>     <int>         <dbl>
1      1 Under 15 female     2         1     50.000000
2      1 Under 15   male     3         3    100.000000
3      1 15 to 50 female    70        68     97.142857
4      1 15 to 50   male    72        32     44.444444
5      1  Over 50 female    13        13    100.000000
6      1  Over 50   male    26         5     19.230769
```

I also tried print:

```
> print( titanic_4, row.names=FALSE)
# A tibble: 18 x 6
# Groups:   Pclass, agecat [9]
   Pclass   agecat    Sex     N survivors perc_survived
    <int>   <fctr>  <chr> <int>     <int>         <dbl>
 1      1 Under 15 female     2         1    50.0000000
 2      1 Under 15   male     3         3   100.0000000
 3      1 15 to 50 female    70        68    97.1428571
 4      1 15 to 50   male    72        32    44.4444444
 5      1  Over 50 female    13        13   100.0000000
 6      1  Over 50   male    26         5    19.2307692
```

And print.data.table:

```
> print.data.table(titanic_4,row.names=FALSE)
Error in print.data.table(titanic_4, row.names = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "print.data.table"
```

Comment: What makes you think that the column alignment is relevant to answering the question you've been given... seems to me that you are overthinking this.

Comment: Dear Kevin, thank you for your comment. Swirl will not accept my current answer and tells me to keep trying.  The only thing that I can see that is left for me to do to make my table look like the desired result is to center the column data.

Comment: Swirl is very picky.  When I attempt to submit my answer, Swirl gives me a very vague clue about formatting the table.  I edited my original post to include the clue.

Comment: I would suggest going back to your lecturer for clarification, the layout of your original desired output is clearly a `tibble` thanks to the data type row being visible. There have been recent package updates to the `tidyverse` affecting printing to the console. My guess is that swirl is hung up of that and not your column alignment.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Swril doesn't have a lecturer. Swirl has been very picky so far, so I just have a feeling that it is trying to get me to center-align the columns.  So far, Swirl only accepts exact answers, nothing close, so it takes a lot of trying to get Swirl to accept a submission.  When I compare my table to the one that swirl wants me to submit, there is clearly a difference in the way that the columns are aligned.  There must be a way to tell R to center the columns.

Comment: There will be an author of the swirl course you are taking, you may need to use the same package versions that were used at the time it was published. In my opinion, you are wasting your time trying to align these columns in the console.

Comment: This is the last task in the 12th chapter.  So far, the intro chapter and the first 12 chapters have all worked great, so I think I might have the right packages for this version of swirl.  This chapter is titled "Data Manipulation", so learning how to change the justification of columns seems like a good fit for the tasks of the chapter.  The author must have thought it was important enough to put it into the chapter, so I don't mind giving it a shot.  I do like how the design of the swirl course is to get help from the r community to solve problems instead of relying on an instructor.

Comment: When I look at the printout the authors of swirl want me to learn how to make, I do think it is definitely visually better looking than the one I am currently making with my code.  I see that in the format.data.frame function, it is possible to set the justification, as well as the width, number of digits, as well as many other things about the visual appearance of the data frame.  However, for some reason, when I try to apply the function in my code, it doesn't change the appearance of my table.  Seems handy to be able to change the way the data looks when it prints.

Comment: The substantive difference I see is that the target output doesn't have rownames. Try `print( tbl, row.names=FALSE)`. If that fails `print.data.table(tbl,row.names=FALSE)` and you might need to prepend the lines with those doubled octothorpes.

Comment: Hi 42, thank you for your observations.  I removed the double octothropes, as those are always included in the r file that swirl uses to give the instructions for the task.  However, your observation about the rownames seems to be just the kind of thing swirl wants me to notice.  I tried your suggestions, but was not yet able to get r to remove the rownames.  I added to the code above to show my failed attempts to remove the rownames.  I'll keep trying.  Thanks